# Twitter Bootstrap accordion collapses when clicking a link in the content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use accordion collapse from bootstrap and i have the following code. Whenever i click the button and the table comes up, i click the "View" which is an html anchor and the table collapses back. I want to keep the table down and stop it from collapsing only whenever the "View" link is clicked.

I have tried the javascript `stopPropagation()` method and it works, but it works for every anchor tag which means i can't even open the accordion panel. i used to call it with html `onclick=""`.

```js
    (function($) {
  "use strict";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
    $("#accordion a").click(function() {
            $(".collapse").collapse('hide');  
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mardav.ga/styles.css">
</head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <div id="content">
        <section class="page-section bg-dark text-white">
            <div class="container text-center">
        </div>
<div data-toggle="true" class="panel-group d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap" id="accordion">
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading d-flex justify-content-center">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#content2020">
      2020
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">  
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="content2020" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">1</th>
              <td>Content 1</td>
              <td class="table-action"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">View</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
    </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code. Also is there any javascript and css you can add to make it clearer what you have tried and what you currently have?

Comment: add sample running code including bootstrap cdn and jquery cdn which you are using

Comment: So when i open the table by clicking on 2020 then the table comes out, when i press view it opens a new tab for google.com but when I go back to your page the table is still down. It seems to be working as intended?
Did you mean that you want it to close when clicking on view? Because it stays open for me until I click on 2020 again..

Comment: css was way to big to fit so i call it externally.

Comment: @FreedomInChaos thanks for your comment, please check the code snippet to understand my problem

Comment: @mardav your snippet isnt even opening the table that you mentioned was working....so not sure what I am supposed to be looking at..

Comment: @FreedomInChaos when you click on 2020, it opens a table on the right that looks exactly like [this](https://snipboard.io/4FYURn.jpg) . So when you click on the "View" button it closes off. I don't want it to close off.